# How to monitor embedded Derby database active connections?

Tags: java, profiling, derby, sqlconnection

While testing an application, which uses **embedded** Derby database, it would be useful to know how many active (not closed) connections are present at the time. Is it possible to get such information? I can use NetBeansIDE profiler, where I can see various `org.apache.derby....` threads. What is the name of thread which is referring to active Derby DB connection? Connections are initiated like:

```
public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:somedatabase;create=true");
}
```

Comment: I assume this is an application which you can't modify? Because otherwise why couldn't you just count the connections each time your application makes a connection or closes a connection? If you can't just count them, then maybe you can monitor the activity by observing the derby.log file, with enough logging options enabled so that connection create and connection close are recorded in the derby log.

Comment: Yes, I can count them, modify an application (written in Java), but there are a lot of threads, and it would be nice to retrieve this information from database to see how application performs. Just like in `MySQL Workbench` as I remember (but monitoring not an embedded database). I can not find `derby.log` file in project directory, just `data/log` folder and `log85.dat, log.ctrl, logmirror.ctrl` files inside... And they are not readable, not text files..